# Case Statement Under another Case Statement in C#

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there was a way in c# to activate a case using another case. E.g

```
{
switch
case "Music":
//play music string
    {
      case "Song Name":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song Name");
      break;

      case "Song 2":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song 2");
      break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can do this? I am also using a speech recognition engine and a synthesizer.

Comment: I indented your code so it shows as code, but I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Could you fix it so the syntax is valid, or are you asking about the syntax itself?

Comment: None of that syntax is correct, even if it was only 1 switch statement. what are you "switching" on in each case? I think you mean to do switch (type) {...} and switch (song) {...} but I can't tell.

Comment: As @dman2306 hinted at, you can have a switch in a switch, but you cannot nest a cases in a branch like that. It must be another switch block.

Comment: @ChrisSprague Can't fall through in C#. `break` is required.

Comment: @Chris there's no automatic fall through in C#, but you can use `goto case "Song 2"` for instance to force it.

Comment: first you need to learn how switch works. then step into further ways you can do to switch. you can skip from one case to another using `goto` statement.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I would avoid using `goto` at all.

Comment: @Arthur `goto case` isn't the same as `goto`, it's an explicit fall-through.

Comment: @ArthurRey, I'd avoid using `switch`/`case` as much as `goto`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but there are probably better ways to achieve whatever your goal is. In order to do that you would need to pass in a struct or object with multiple attributes so that the value being switched on can be extracted once the first switch hits the correct case.

TL;DR nested switch cases are possible, but unwise.

Comment: Why is it unwise? It's done all the time. You might have a main switch on something like switch(commandType). Then each case might fire off a function that handles that command. Inside that function you might have a switch(subcommand). I have no idea why this is "unwise"

Comment: It is done frequently, but that doesnt make it a good idea. I consider it unwise because it makes the code messy and verbose, making it difficult to understand what is happening. This is a problem with MOST nesting. In the case of switch cases there is also the possibility of accidentily having a piece fall through to the wrong case from the other switch. This could be as simple as for getting a semicolon but may be a very difficult error to find.

Comment: I don't think forgetting a semicolon is a good explanation of it being a bad idea. By that logic, using an if() is "unwise" because accidentally *adding* a semicolon introduces a bug that is difficult to find. `if (something); callSomeMethod();` why does callSomeMethod always get called? Nesting, either directly, or abstracted via function calls, is a necessity of complex programming.

Comment: Maybe that waas not a good example but the point is that finding an error in a nested switchcase can be especially difficult because of the possibility of one switch falling through into the other inadvertantly. Nesting is of course necessary at times, but should be avoided when possible. My suggestion incidentily was going to be the use of an abstractedmethod call to resolve that problem, but I hit my character limit in the previous response and so was unable to mention it.

Comment: @dman2306, it's unwise because it creates high cyclomatic complexity in the code. In other words, it creates code that is difficult to read; difficult to test and highly error prone. `switch` statements are so bad for this that they can legitimately be seen as a code smell. It is possible to write very readable, functional and succinct C# code without ever using `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not:

```
switch (action)
{
case "Music":
  switch(songName
  {
      case "Song Name":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song Name");
      break;

      case "Song 2":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song 2");
      break;
  }
case "Video":
  break;
}
```

But, it seems like this might be easier to maintain and easier to read:

```
public MyActionMethod(MyAction action)
{
  switch (action)
  {
    case Music:
      MessageSong(songName);
      break;
    case Video:
      break;
  }
}

public void MessageSong(string songName)
{
  switch(songName)
  {
    case "Song Name":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song Name");
      break;

    case "Song 2":
      messagebox.show("Playing Song 2");
      break;
  }
}

public enum MyAction
{
  NoAction,
  Music,
  Video
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't correct, however, I understand you want a switch inside another switch statement? that's doable:

```
string type = "Music";
string songName = "song1";
switch(type)
  {
    case "Music":
      {
         switch(songName)
           {
              case "song1":
               //play song1
               break;

              case "song2":
              //play song2
              break;
           }
       }break;

   case "SomeOtherType":
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this?

```
        string on1 = "Music";
        string on2 = "Song Name";

        switch (on1) {
            case "Music":
                switch (on2)
                {
                    case "Song Name":
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Playing Song Name");
                        break;

                    case "Song 2":
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Playing Song 2");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of what you mean but here is my take:

```
string type = "";
string song = "";

switch (type)
{
    case "Music":
        switch (song)
        {
            case "Song Name":
                messagebox.show("Playing Song Name");
                break;

            case "Song 2":
                messagebox.show("Playing Song 2");
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        // whatever
        break;
}
```

Edit: Since you are doing the same action in the second switch, you can just do:

```
string type = "";
string song = "";

switch (type)
{
    case "Music":
        messagebox.show("Playing " + song);
        break;

    default:
        // whatever
        break;
}
```